# Google sheets sidebar form - set default values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a spreadsheet sidebar that allows a user to input data to create records, as well as edit them. So far I understand how to create the sidebar and display it. I've got a working form that can submit values.

What I am struggling with is how to pre-populate the forms. Form instance some records are associated with others, and I'd like to have a hidden field to store and eventually submit the associated id. Eventually users should also be able to edit records and I'd like to use the same form and just populate the fields and reuse the same submission flow.

I've tried a few different things found on here and other places, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the HTML for the sidebar template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->
    <style>
    </style>

    <script>
    // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

    $('#accountId').val(<? data.accountId ?>);

    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(alertSuccess).createContact(formObject);
    }

    function alertSuccess(message) {
      var div = document.getElementById('alert');
      div.innerHTML = "<p>" + message + "</p>";
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Enter Contact Info</p>

    <form id="contact" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      Account Id: <br>
      <input type="number" name="accountId" value="0" id="accountId" /><br>
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
      Phone Number:<br>
      <input type="text" name="phone"/><br>
      Email:<br>
      <input type="email" name="email"/><br>
      Contact Type:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="emergency" checked> Emergency<br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="guardian" checked> Guardian<br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="other" checked> Other<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="alert"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the accompanying .gs file:

```
var AlternativeContact = ObjectModel("AlternativeContacts");

function newContact() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("new_contact");
  var id = ACCOUNT_MANAGER.getRange("M4").getValue();
  htmlOutput.data = {accountId: id};

  UI.showSidebar(htmlOutput.evaluate());
}

function createContact(contactJSON) {
  var newContact = new AlternativeContact(contactJSON);
  newContact.save();
  return "Success!";
}
```

The first line that uses ObjectModel is creating and ORM around the data sheet.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Couple changes and it seems to be working in a basic way.

First, in the scriptlet, i needed to us the printing tag. so use  in stead of . This was causing the value to not be used in the rendered template.

Second, I changed my jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("input#accountId").val(<?= data.accountId ?>);
    });
```

If anyone is able to answer, I'd be curious why using the $(document).ready is needed. Doesn't everything in the  get run? is it an order of operation thing?